# How can I detect which on which frame was a Button Clicked in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a question. I have this code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class new_f:
    def __init__(self,root,num):
        self.new_frame=tk.Frame(root,width=100,height=100,bg='white',bd=3,relief=tk.GROOVE)
        self.new_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT,fill=tk.X,expand=True)

        self.num=num

    def add_label(self,t):
        self.l1=tk.Label(self.new_frame,bg='white',text=t)
        self.l1.pack()

    def return_instance(self):
        return self.num

class Main_win:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.bind_number=0
        self.current_index=0

        self.instance_list=[]

        self.b1=tk.Button(self.root,text='Add Frame',command=self.add_frame_win)
        self.b1.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

        self.b2=tk.Button(self.root,text='Add text',command=self.add_text_frame)
        self.b2.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

    def return_instance_num(self,num,*args):
        self.current_index=num

    def add_frame_win(self):
        new_in=new_f(self.root,self.bind_number)
        self.instance_list.append(new_in)

        new_in.new_frame.bind('<Button-1>',lambda evnt: self.return_instance_num(new_in.return_instance()))
        #self.current_index=new_in.return_instance()
        self.bind_number+=1

    def add_text_frame(self):
        instance=self.instance_list[self.current_index]
        instance.add_label('Hello World')

root=tk.Tk()
ob=Main_win(root)
root.mainloop()
```

What I a trying to achieve is that I want to detect on which frame was the left mouse-button clicked so as to make that Frame active and add the labels to that particular Frame. 
However, I am stuck on how would I go about writing the code. I need a new class Because I don't know how many frames will the user need.

This is a short example of the code I will be implementing later. So my question is:

- How will I go to detect which frame was picked so as to make it active to add the labels?

Comment: I've been thinking about your project and realized another way to achieve the same result. My first effort was to basically follow your code and make a few modifications, but now the code has a lot of unused components. So I've taken a different approach that solves the problem but also opens up the possibility of populating frames with other tk objects. I'll post it now as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In this approach I have label `l1` bound to `Button-1`

This was achieved by passing `self` to `new_f` instead of `root`
and binding `self.l1` to `Button-1`

```py
import tkinter as tk

class new_f:
    def __init__(self, prog, num):
        self.prog = prog
        self.new_frame = tk.Frame(prog.root, width = 100, height = 100, bg = 'white', bd = 3, relief = tk.GROOVE)
        self.new_frame.pack(side = tk.LEFT, fill = tk.X, expand = True)

        self.num = num

    def add_label(self, t):
        self.l1 = tk.Label(self.new_frame, bg = 'white', text = t)
        self.l1.pack()
        # binding button-1 press to label
        self.l1.bind("<Button-1>", lambda evnt: self.prog.return_instance_num(self.return_instance()))

    def return_instance(self):
        return self.num

class Main_win:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.bind_number = 0
        self.current_index = 0

        self.instance_list = []

        self.b1 = tk.Button(self.root, text = 'Add Frame', command = self.add_frame_win)
        self.b1.pack(side = tk.BOTTOM)

        self.b2 = tk.Button(self.root, text = 'Add text', command = self.add_text_frame)
        self.b2.pack(side = tk.BOTTOM)

    def return_instance_num(self, num, *args):
        self.current_index = num

    def add_frame_win(self):
        # note passing self not root
        new_in = new_f(self, self.bind_number)
        self.instance_list.append(new_in)

        new_in.new_frame.bind('<Button-1>', lambda evnt: self.return_instance_num(new_in.return_instance()))
        #self.current_index = new_in.return_instance()
        self.bind_number = self.bind_number + 1

    def add_text_frame(self):
        instance = self.instance_list[self.current_index]
        instance.add_label('Hello World')

root = tk.Tk()
ob = Main_win(root)
# This necessary to prevent error if user hits 'Add text' before 'Add Frame'
ob.add_frame_win()
root.mainloop()
```

Here is an alternative method that uses dictionaries to store `l1` and `new_frame` objects as keys and `new_f` instances as values.

This method can be used for other `tkinter` objects (Entry, Listbox, Text, Canvas)

```py
import tkinter as tk

class new_f:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = tk.Frame(
            parent.root, width = 100, height = 100,
            bg = "white", bd = 3, relief = tk.GROOVE)
        self.frame.pack(
            side = tk.LEFT, fill = tk.X, expand = True)
        self.frame.bind("<Button-1>", parent.get_current_frame)

    def add_label(self, t):
        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame, bg = "white", text = t)
        self.label.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)
        # bind button-1 to label, set instance_label and current to self
        self.label.bind("<Button-1>", self.parent.get_current_label)
        self.parent.instance_label[self.label] = self.parent.current = self

class Main_win:

    instance_label = dict() # This method can be expanded for other objects
    instance_frame = dict() # that you may want to create in frames
    
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.b1 = tk.Button(
            self.root, text = "Add Frame", command = self.add_frame_win)
        self.b1.pack(side = tk.BOTTOM)
        self.b2 = tk.Button(
            self.root, text = "Add text", command = self.add_text_frame)
        self.b2.pack(side = tk.BOTTOM)

    def get_current_label(self, ev):
        self.current = self.instance_label[ev.widget]

    def get_current_frame(self, ev):
        self.current = self.instance_frame[ev.widget]

    def add_frame_win(self):
        # note passing self not root
        self.new_in = new_f(self)
        self.instance_frame[self.new_in.frame] = self.current = self.new_in

    def add_text_frame(self):
        # Change message with entry tool?
        self.current.add_label("Hello World")

root = tk.Tk()
ob = Main_win(root)
# This necessary to prevent error if user hits 'Add text' before 'Add Frame'
ob.add_frame_win()
root.mainloop()
```